# Can $x^2 +x + 2 = 10^x$ be solved using algebra?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I know this can be solved by numerical methods but I would like to know whether this can be solved using logs or something similar.

Thanks

Comment: Unless there is a happy coincidence, one can typically not solve explicitly equations in one variable where the variable occurs both inside and outside a transcendental expression, at least not in terms of the usual operations and elementary functions.

Comment: Approximation with graphical method...

Comment: Thank you Travis, that is the information I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Travis [answers in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952296/can-x2-x-2-10x-be-solved-using-algebra/952303#comment1959769_952296):

> Unless there is a happy coincidence, one can typically not solve explicitly equations in one variable where the variable occurs both inside and outside a transcendental expression, at least not in terms of the usual operations and elementary functions.